# How to access variables in whole SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to access variables in whole script that is divided to few sections by `GO` command. How to do that?

Below is source example (that doesn't work):

```
--script info (begining of script file)  
DECLARE @ScriptCode NVARCHAR (20)  = '20120330-01'  

--some queries  
GO  

--and there I cannot use @ScriptCode variable 
INSERT INTO DBScriptsHistory(ScriptCode) VALUES(@ScriptCode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, because variables exist only within the current batch. Assuming that you need to use the GO statement (e.g. CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a batch), the simplest solution is probably to use [sqlcmd scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) statement is a batch separator for the different SQL client tools - it is not part of SQL.

Each batch is separate from the other - just remove the `GO` statement.

See [GO (Tranasct-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> The scope of local (user-defined) variables is limited to a batch, and cannot be referenced after a GO command.

Comment: Removing GO will work in the specific case that the OP showed, but it will not work in the general case because sometimes GO is required: many (most?) CREATE statements must be the first statement in a batch.

Comment: I know what for is GO, but how to for example add 2 procedures without GO? I cannot.

Comment: @MarekKwiendacz - Then you need to rethink you scripts. Don't use local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the GO keyword, it will work. Once you have called GO, the variable is no longer in scope.